# Startup script in crontab doesn't work on reboot

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

On system reboot `init 6` I would like to start my services for my rails project the script contains pull changes from git, run bundle install and run delayed job workers

The script is in `/etc/init.d/app-startup-script`

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/deploy/source/myapp

git pull origin development

bundle install

bundle exec cap staging deploy

touch /home/deploy/hello.txt (added this to test if it will create file on reboot)
```

and I run this script inside `crontab -e` on reboot

```
@reboot /etc/init.d/app-startup-script
```

I confirm the app-startup-script is running by manually running it using 
`/etc/init.d/app-startup-script`

but when I reboot the system using

```
sudo su - 
init 6
```

then ssh again to my server it only creates the hello.txt file in /home/deploy but didn't start my rails services

Comment: `/etc/init.d` is for `init` startup scripts; you want to find a better place for this one. Perhaps `/usr/local/bin/app-startup-script`

Comment: That might accidentally also fix the script so that it runs only when networks are up and stable etc.

Comment: @tripleee I moved the script from /etc/init.d to /usr/local/bin/ It creates hello.txt file but does not run the rails services

Comment: Run it with error output to a file so you can see what's going wrong. I guess it will have produced errors in your system logs but where exactly is pretty platform-dependent. `@reboot /usr/local/bin/app-startup-script >>/home/you/app-startup.log 2>&1` should make them visible in your home directory (where obviously adjust the path).

Comment: Add a `set -e` at the top of your shell script. That causes it to abort on errors. Also, check the existing output.

Comment: How about adding the script to /etc/rc.local? You'll have to use sudo access though to edit this file.

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

Comment: Would you be willing to switch to `systemd` service ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would be willing to switch to `systemd` services then,

Your startup script,

```
$ cat start.bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/deploy/source/myapp

git pull origin development
bundle install
bundle exec cap staging deploy
touch /home/deploy/hello.txt (added this to test if it will create file on reboot)
```

Your service file,

```
$ cat yourapp.service
[Unit]
Description=Your rail app
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root # if it should be run as root, otherwise specify the user
ExecStart=/path/to/start.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then do,

```
$ chmod +x start.bash
$ cp yourapp.service /etc/systemd/system/

$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable yourapp.service # this should make sure, the service starts on boot
```